# PHP: SQLite returns values as strings

Tags: php, laravel, sqlite

I'm using SQLite with Laravel and find it quite annoying that all values are returned as strings. Is there a way to enable automatic type casting (like the MySQL native driver [mysqlnd] does)?
I know about the `$casts` attribute, I'm looking for an app-independent solution to make the database driver do the casting.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can automatically cast. Add this property to your model.

```
protected $casts = [
    'is_admin' => 'boolean',
    'count' => 'integer'
];
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that point in my question. I'm looking for an app-independent solution to make the database driver do the casting.